# ps command not giving output in home directory

Tags: solaris, path, ps

I am logging into a solaris server, switching to bash, then switching to another user "sruser" and switching to bash.

`/home/batch/sruser/` is the home directory of the user "sruser".

The issue is ps is not giving any output when run in the home directory -

```
# pwd
 /home/batch/sruser/
# ps
# cd dir1
 /home/batch/sruser/dir1
# ps 
   PID TTY      TIME CMD
 17867 pts/1789 0:00 bash
 17165 pts/1789 0:00 ksh
 20435 pts/1789 0:00 ps
#
```

Don't know what could be the issue. Don't even know where to start looking for whatever could be the issue.

Comment: Maybe the *sruser* has *.* (cwd) in *$PATH* and a *ps* executable in his home directory?

Comment: try `type ps` or `which ps` to see what is being executed

Comment: Hope you didn't run that as `root`?  But how would `.` end up in root's `PATH`?  Hope you didn't add it there yourself.

Comment: If `type ps` shows that `/usr/bin/ps` is being executed, run `truss ps` to see what's going on. (But `.` in `$PATH` is the most obvious explanation.)

Comment: @guido Thanks for the answer.
@phunehehe @Gilles Thanks to you guys, TIL 3 new commands (I'm a UNIX newb)

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/why-do-we-use-to-execute-a-file/4459#4459

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$PATH` has `.`(cwd) and there is a file `ps` with executable permissions in the home directory.

```
# ls -lrt *ps*
-rwxrw-r--   1 sruser  batch          0 Jun 2 2010 ps
# type ps
ps is hashed (./ps)
# which ps
./ps
```

Hence the command was not giving any output.

Comment: "ps" has no executable permission bits set in your ls output. It should then be ignored by the shell while exploring your PATH.

Comment: @jlliagre thanks for correcting me. i copied the wrong snippet. it does have a executable permission.

Comment: In any case, having . in your PATH as root is a poor practice but having it before the standard /bin, /usr/bin, sbin directories is quite suicidal.

Comment: Note that the more traditional way to include the current directory in `$PATH` is with the empty string. `PATH=/bin:` has the current directory last and `PATH=:/bin:/usr/bin` has it first. Incidentally, that latter one is the default `$PATH` (!) on GNU/Linux systems (for `execvp`, `env`...) when `PATH` is unset.