# Why do you need the "./" when executing programs in the current directory?

Tags: shell, executable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do we use “./” to execute a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/why-do-we-use-to-execute-a-file)

It seems redundant and gets annoying after a while -- is there a way to change this? If not, can somebody explain the reasoning behind this?

Thanks!

Comment: Aren't duplicates flagged here (it does not appear as reson in the list). Should I ask this on meta? Okay - I will do so!

Answer (score 6):

You don't, if the current directory is in your path and there isn't another executable with the same name in a directory named earlier in the path.    If either of these conditions isn't true, ./ effectively says "look here".

Although you can add "." to your path, it isn't advisable, since that opens the door for unexpected (or malicious) results if you execute a command from a directory that has executables that match the name of system commands.

Comment: This gets especially dangerous when executing shell scripts with `su` privileges, since it fails to sanitize the environment beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You do if your current directory is not in your path.  If you ever log in as root or are a sudoer, I do not recommend you add your current directory to your path.  Just put up with the ./

If you wish, make a directory in your home directory called `bin`.  Then add this directory to your search path. It's a good place to put your general purpose housekeeping scripts.

Answer (score 0):

isnt it much easier than running your program using `sh yourprogram.sh` or `python yourprogram.py` ?