# Why can I only run a .sh file from the parent directory, not the child directory

Tags: linux, directory, directory-structure

I noticed that this does not work:

```
/tomcatDirectory/bin $ startup.sh //command not found
```

but this does work

```
/tomcatDirectory $ bin/startup.sh
```

I am used to Windows. It seems counter-intuitive to me that I can not run a program from its working directory, only from the parent folder.

What's the bigger picture of what's happening here?

Comment: See the related [Why do you need the “./” when executing programs in the current directory?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16022/why-do-you-need-the-when-executing-programs-in-the-current-directory) too.

Comment: You could put that bin in your path.  Add `export PATH=$PATH:/tomcatDirectory/bin` to `~/.profile`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current directory (i.e., `.`) is not in your path. Try with

```
./startup.sh
```

You can check your path with

```
echo ${PATH}
```

You *could* add the current directory (`.`) to your path but this is considered a risk (especially if `.` is before other directories): when typing a command the shell will first try to execute it in the current directory. This will execute what is there instead of the *default* one.

Summarizing: just start executables in the current directory with `./` in front of them.

Answer (score 0):

Because "startup.sh" doesn't really look like a path to file and you don't have `.` in your PATH environment variable. But still you can start it as `./startup.sh`