# Is it safe to add . to my PATH? How come?

Tags: path

I've seen people mention in [other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12492/3629) [answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64665/3629) that it's a bad idea to include the current working directory ('`.`') in your `$PATH` environment variable, but haven't been able to find a question specifically addressing the issue.

So, why shouldn't I add `.` to my path?  And if despite all warnings I do it anyway, what do I have to watch out for?  Is it safer to add it to the end than to the the start?

Comment: [unix-faq: What's wrong with having '.' in your $PATH](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part2/section-13.html)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you're the only user on the machine it's okay, as long as you know what you're doing. The general concern is that by having your current directory in `PATH`, you cannot see commands as a constant list. If you need to run a script/program from your current directory, you can always explicitly run it by prepending `./` to its name (you telling the system "I want to run this file from my current directory").

Say, now you have all these little scripts all over your filesystem; one day you'll run the wrong one for sure. So, having your `PATH` as a predefined list of static paths is all about order and saving oneself from a potential problem.

However, if you're going to add `.` to your `PATH`, I suggest appending it to the end of the list (`export PATH=$PATH:.`). At least you won't override system-wide binaries this way.

If you're a root on the system and have system exposed to other users' accounts, having `.` in `PATH` is a huge security risk: you can `cd` to some user's directory, and unintentionally run a malicious script there only because you mistyped a thing or script that has the same name as a system-wide binary.

Comment: +Accept for the underlying theory and for mentioning that the problems can still exist even when you're the only user on the system.  Both answers bring up excellent points.  I'll add that any time you share directories with another user, there is increased risk, whether you're root or not.

Comment: even as the only user on the machine: everytime you extract an untrusted tar it can place an `ls` in your current directory. next you run `ls` to inspect the extracted files and you have already run the malicious code.

Comment: @lesmana That couldn't happen if you have `.` at the end of `PATH` though, could it?

Comment: @flarn2006 not _exactly_ that, no, but the tar could put `sl` or `lss` for example in the current directory, and if you mistype `ls` as one of those options then it will execute that malicious code

Answer (score 38):

The risk is someone put a malicious executable in the directory that happen to be your current one.

The worst case happen when:

- you are logged as root as the malicious command has unlimited damage power
- `.` is at the beginning of your PATH as standard commands can be overridden without you noticing it (typically an `ls` which could hide itself from the list).

The risk is much lower if you are logged as a regular user and have the `.` at the end of your PATH but it still exists:

- someone might find out you frequently mistype a command and install a matching one
- someone might install a fake command with the name of one that is not installed.

Note that in any case, the risk is still there even if you are the only user of the machine. Malicious software would be installed if, for example, you happen to extract an archive downloaded from a malicious or compromised site.

Comment: Install `sl` to see how often point 3 happens.

Comment: or `alias l=\`ls\``.

Comment: it doesn't have to be malicious. I expect `ls` to get a directory listing but some project I download might have a `ls` script in their root project folder as a shortcut to something else. `ls` is probably a bad example but I can certainly imagine `e` for edit, `d` for debug, `m` for make, `b` for build. I have some of those myself globally. If I type `m` I expect make to launch (my shortcut), not some local script called `m` to execute.

Comment: @gman Right. A non malicious command might unwittingly have adverse effects indeed. Note that single letter commands/aliases were frowned upon since Unix inception due to the high risk of mistyping. Rare standard ones are `w` and `[`.

Answer (score 6):

Even if you are always very careful with what you type, putting `.` to your `PATH`, even at the end, is still insecure because some programs change the current directory to `/tmp` (which is world writable) and may also try execute utilities that are actually not installed, thus defaulting to what is in `/tmp`. If this occurs, this is a vector of attack.

Note also that there isn't much drawback of avoiding `.` in `PATH`, because `./` is easy to type (in particular on keyboards like QWERTY, where these characters are on consecutive keys and do not need Shift) and using `./` will also help completion, thus potentially saving keystrokes at the end.

If you really want to be able to type commands from the current directory, then modern shells (like zsh, with its `command_not_found_handler`) may provide features to do that safely, i.e. allowing you to add all the security checks you want in the handler, before the command is executed.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's dangerous. If you want to run a program `a` in the current directory just run `./a`.

The reason that is is dangerous is that you risk running a trojan horse planted by someone else in a directory that you access.

Imagine what can happen when you download a tarfile with a binary called `ls`.