# chmod – execute permission for non-admins?

Tags: linux, chmod, bashrc

I have used `chmod` to make all the contents of a directory executable.  However, when I try to run one of the programs in that directory as a regular user (me), I get a "command not found" message.  If I run as `su`, the programs run.  What am I missing?  I am running Fedora 22.
Here is a complete bash session. (It's also showing that my git installation is incomplete, but I think that's irrelevant.)

```
bash: home/brian/git-completion.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/brian/git-prompt.sh: No such file or directory
bash: __git_ps1: command not found...
brian ~ $ ipython
bash: ipython: command not found...
Similar command is: 'python'
bash: __git_ps1: command not found...
brian ~ $ su
Password: 
bash: home/brian/git-completion.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /root/git-prompt.sh: No such file or directory
bash: __git_ps1: command not found...
root brian $ ipython
Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 28 2015, 17:02:03) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 3.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]:
```

In addition, here is a complete listing of my .bashrc:

```
sudo# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi

# Enable tab completion
source home/brian/git-completion.bash

# colors!
green="\[\033[0;32m\]"
blue="\[\033[0;34m\]"
purple="\[\033[0;35m\]"
reset="\[\033[0m\]"

# Change command prompt
source ~/git-prompt.sh
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
# '\u' adds the name of the current user to the prompt
# '\$(__git_ps1)' adds git-related stuff
# '\W' adds the name of the current directory
export PS1="$purple\u$green\$(__git_ps1)$blue \W $ $reset"

# added by Anaconda 2.3.0 installer
export PATH="/root/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: I think you're making a mistake as the error you get does not concern permissions. Please post all your output.

Comment: Try running the command with the relative path ./command_name

Comment: Do regular users have read and execute permissions on the directory itself (and all parent directories)?  If the user's don't have execute on the directory they can't access any of the files in it, even if they would have permission for that file--they can't get to it.

Comment: Also, the changes to permissions made by the `chmod` command are always permanent -- whether you are a privileged or an unprivileged user.

Comment: You have an unsafe path for root. Probably got the current directory in it.

Comment: Could you explain about the unsafe path?  I have always been a bit confused about how Fedora has a /root directory at what I think of as the root level.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it has nothing to do with permissions.  You'd see a "permission denied", not a "command not found".

What's going on is that you seem to have `.` in your `$PATH` as root (which is *insane*), but not for your own account.

[Is it safe to add . to my PATH? How come?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65700/is-it-safe-to-add-to-my-path-how-come)

Answer: no.  You unpack a tar.gz, `cd` into the directory, and run `ls`.  There's an executable in the directory called `ls`, which runs instead of `/bin/ls`.  It modified your `~/.bashrc` so the next time your run `su` and type in the root password, the attacker owns your machine.

If you want to run something in the current directory, run `./cmd`

Comment: I think I get it.  Now for a very practical and dumb question:  where do I find the 2 paths (mine as user and root) to change them?

Comment: @BrianM: Usually they're set in your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`.  Root has its own versions of those files, if you're using `su` instead of `sudo`.  (Root's home directory is `/root`.  Don't be confused by `/` being called the root filesystem; that's the root-of-the-tree sense, rather than the `root` user.)

Comment: I realize we shouldn't be communicating so much via comments but I don't yet have chat privileges. The two .bashrc files are identical''' sudo# .bashrc
alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'
. /etc/bashrc
fi
source home/brian/git-completion.bash
green="\[\033[0;32m\]"
blue="\[\033[0;34m\]"
purple="\[\033[0;35m\]"
reset="\[\033[0m\]"
source ~/git-prompt.sh
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
export PS1="$purple\u$green\$(__git_ps1)$blue \W $ $reset"

# added by Anaconda 2.3.0 installer
export PATH="/root/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

Comment: Sorry for the messy formatting of the previous comment.  Please see the edited OP for the .bashrc.  Question: what should be changed where?  I was never aware of the multiple paths.  Thanks for that info (and all your help)

Comment: @BrianM: There are several places `PATH` can be modified.  Google should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be neither a PATH nor a permissions problem.  Anaconda Python was installed in my /root directory, which meant that it could only be accessed by a superuser.  Reinstalling Anaconda in home solved the problem.