# Why didn't a command work when ran in its directory?

Tags: path, command

Installing OpenNMS and had a bit of a snag. Issue resolved but it left me wondering...

Why doesn't this work:

```
[nac@localhost /]$ cd opt/opennms/bin/
[nac@localhost bin]$ runjava -s
-bash: runjava: command not found
```

...but this does:

```
[nac@localhost /]$ opt/opennms/bin/runjava -s
runjava: Looking for an appropriate JRE...
runjava: Checking for an appropriate JRE in JAVA_HOME...
runjava: skipping... JAVA_HOME not set
runjava: Checking JRE in user's path: "/usr/bin/java"...
runjava: found an appropriate JRE in user's path: "/usr/bin/java"
```

I'm using cygwin. ssh into a fedora box. the output is green for  `ls /opt/opennms/bin`  if that helps...

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331075/why-do-you-need-dot-slash-before-script-name-to-run-it-in-bash

Comment: @Jesse_b you can't have duplicates across sites.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to add . to my PATH? How come?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65700/is-it-safe-to-add-to-my-path-how-come)

Comment: It's because `.` (current directory) is not a path the shell looks for executables in; https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65700/is-it-safe-to-add-to-my-path-how-come explains why.

Comment: @derobert No it's not. The solution does not necessarily involve adding `.` to `$PATH`.

Comment: @Kusalananda I understood OP's question as why `runjava` from the directory it's in doesn't work (presumably compared to Windows/DOS where it does work). `.` not being in the path is the reason. That question explains why `.` is not in the path.

Comment: @derobert But it doesn't give an answer to the OPs issue... It just explains why the obvious solution is a bad one.

Comment: @Kusalananda I see that reading is possible, now that you've pointed it out. I didn't read it as the OP wanting to change the behavior, just understand why it was different than what he's used to (the DOS/Windows behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `.` is not part of your `$PATH`.  Unix will only search for executable programs in those directories listed in `$PATH`.

Further, having `.` in `$PATH` is a security risk, so don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

Your `$PATH` does not contain the current directory, `.`.  Therefore, the `runjava` executable is not found when you try to execute it without a path while located in its directory.

It also does not contain `/opt/opennms/bin`. If it had done, typing `runjava` (while in any directory) would have located the executable there.

A few solutions:

1. Always use the path to the executable, either `/opt/opennms/bin/runjava`, or `./runjava` if you are within the `/opt/opennms/bin` directory.
2. Add `/opt/opennms/bin` to your path.  To do this, edit your shell initialization file (`.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` for `bash`) and add the line

   ```
   PATH="$PATH:/opt/opennms/bin"
   ```

   Then restart the Cygwin session.
3. Create an alias:

   ```
   alias runjava=/opt/opennms/runjava
   ```

   This would be added to a shell startup file. This will run the `runjava` executable as if you had typed the complete path to it when you give the command `runjava`.

You do not want to add `.` to the `PATH` variable. For a discussion about that, see the question "[Is it safe to add . to my PATH? How come?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65700/is-it-safe-to-add-to-my-path-how-come)"

Comment: This is probably not a good idea. I think that directory contains a bunch of generic and conflicting stuff you don't want in PATH. E.g., https://issues.opennms.org/browse/NMS-9102 suggests it contains an `install` command.

Comment: @derobert Having it last in the path will make sure that `install` is picked up from a proper place if needed. The OpenNMS `install` would very likely have to be run with a complete path.

Comment: I think having conflicting names in $PATH is generally a bad idea, unless you're explicitly intending to override one (e.g., by putting it first). Its reasonably unlikely that `install` is missing from the system paths, but if it were then some interesting errors (or worse) would result when a makefile winds up running OpenNMS's `install` command by mistake. And I wonder how many other potential issues like that exist in said directory; I couldn't find a file listing online.

Comment: @derobert An alias may be a good solution then...

Comment: @derobert Coming back to an old thread... Also note that some systems _on purpose_ put different utilities with the same name in `$PATH` (e.g. Solaris). The composition of `$PATH` then picks what "personality" the current shell session has.