# What' the subtle difference between `test.sh` and `./test.sh`

Tags: shell

I have the following script:

```
$ cat test.sh
#! /usr/local/bin/bash
date
```

Run it,

```
$ test.sh
-bash: test.sh: command not found
```

It works

```
$ ./test.sh
Thu Oct 25 18:04:45 CST 2018
```

Nonetheless, I am aware that `test.sh` is identical  to `./test.sh`,

```
$ file test.sh
test.sh: Bourne-Again shell script text executable, ASCII text
$ file ./test.sh
./test.sh: Bourne-Again shell script text executable, ASCII text
```

What' the subtle difference between `test.sh` and `./test.sh`?

Comment: You can run your script without `./` and from any location if you add directory where the script is stored to `$PATH` variable. The same is for Windows, it's not Linux/UNIX specific

Comment: See also [Why do we use “./” to execute a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/why-do-we-use-to-execute-a-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are not identical ways to run a command.  With `./test.sh`, you run the `test.sh` script in the current directory.  With `test.sh`, you run the first found `test.sh` in your `$PATH`.

Had you called the script `test`, then running just `test` would have used the `test` utility that is likely built into your shell (which does not produce any output), whereas running `./test` would have executed your script.

Related:

- [Why do we use "./" to execute a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4430)
- [Is it safe to add . to my PATH? How come?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65700)