# Why is `time` not working on basic Bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, time

`echo -e '#!/bin/bash\nsleep 10' > time_test.sh && chmod +x time_test.sh && time time_test.sh`

```
time_test.sh: No such file or directory

real    0m0.186s
user    0m0.105s
sys     0m0.074s
```

I must be missing something..?

EDIT: I missed the error, partially because I was ignoring an error in a non-example script (it is added now). The moral seems to be that commands that run the script in some fashion need its location, where as other built-ins like `cat` dont. So, maybe the better question is, is that a decent definition of which commands need the location, or I suppose just trial and error, if there is an error the script can't be found, to add the `./` or path information.. I suppose anything that fails without it being marked executable. I wonder which other common commands people use that encounter this.

Comment: Your execution would have failed unless you have `.` in your PATH which you [should not do](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65700/237982).  You have to execute the script like `./time_test.sh` or `bash time_test.sh`

Comment: @jesse_b I'm trying to use `time` on the script. I need to have something similar to `time time_test.sh`. I tried `time bash time_test.sh` already.  `bash time time_test.sh` says "/usr/bin/time: cannot execute binary file".

Comment: @alchemy `time ./time_test.sh`

Comment: @jesse_b same result.. (sorry for the double comment)

Comment: Yeah the only time you should get "cannot execute binary file" is from `bash time ...` but `time bash ...` or `time ./time_test.sh` should absolutely not produce that

Comment: @jesse_b understood, but still no joy.. does it work for you? Im on up-to-date Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski sorry, I am blind.. yes there is.. I corrected the output

Comment: @jesse_b my bad.. you are correct. I switched VMs to make sure my shell options I had messed with werent affecting it.. and it didnt find the file. But adding `./` works. So all commands that run a script have to be told where it is, versus builtins like `cat` that can see it in the pwd..?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, so I had some other errors in a non-example script that I was troubleshooting, that I was ignoring visually.. dont know why didnt see that.. you were correct.

Comment: What happens when you run the script without `time`? How are you running it?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor jesse_b and Kamil got it.. `time` needs the explicit location of the script to run.

Comment: is this not also true of your shell?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor other non-executing commands of course dont need the explicit location if running in the pwd of the script. Sorry, silly mistake I could have seen the error for, but maybe this will help someone else out.

Comment: If you PATH includes `.`, then you should fix it. It is a serous security vulnerability (e.g. make an executable script called `ls`, then try to check for its existence using `ls`. Hopefully the script does nothing bad), and can also lead to much annoyance.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor great, thanks.. that is actually not the problem

Comment: The convention is `time_test.sh` means a file in the current working directory if we're about to read or write to the file. If we're about to *execute* `time_test.sh` then by convention it means a file named `time_test.sh` somewhere in `$PATH`. Note `.` is usually not in `$PATH`, so to execute `./time_test.sh` you need to explicitly write this `./`. There are subtleties, e.g. `bash time_test.sh` works because it *reads* the file (to interpret it, but the file does not need to be executable). `time time_test.sh` is simple though: it tries to truly *execute* `time_test.sh`, so it uses `$PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

This was already answered in the comments, but I will answer it here as you seem to have missed it.

When you run a command, it searches for the command file in the directories listed in your `$PATH` variable (unless the command is an alias or a shell function). This usually does not include the current working directory (this differs from MS-Windows), because this would cause security problems, e.g. making a script called `ls`.

Solution: run the script using `time ./time_test.sh` not with `time time_test.sh`. (note: the file should not end with a `.sh`, it is bad form, and leaks implementation details.)

Comment: Just to be technical here, "When you run a command.." should be "When you run a command that executes a file" I think. That was my issue. I added a bit more context in the Question.

Comment: No. It does it script or not. It is part of the Unix philosophy, that everything that is executable is a command/program. The language does not matter. Are you running scripts with `bash script-name`. If so then don't. You made it executable, you added a `#!` line.

Comment: I think youre missing how simple my issue was.. compare to `cat <file>` that does not need the `./` for example `cat ./<file>`..  but a command like `time` executing <file> does.

Comment: @alchemy Looking at the content of a file, e.g., using `cat` is _generally_ less destructive than executing the contents of the file. So `cat <file>` will look for <file> in the relative path. To execute `<file>`, the program needs to be in your `$PATH` or you need to give an explicit path name in the command.

Comment: @doneal24 yes, thanks.. I just dont use commands that often that execute files/scripts manually (beside `bash` or `.` occasionally)

Comment: @doneal24 Actually file writing can be destructive `echo >` which doesnt need explicit location (although I use `set -o noclobber`).. I suppose it might be more clear if it did.. but again I wonder how many other commands like `time` even show this distinction.

Comment: Yes simple is the point. It is simpler that you think. It looks like you are special casing something. The problem has nothing to do with the `time` command (no distinction). You will get the same error if just running the command without `time`. If you can identify what you are doing different (when you don't need to), then it will fix this an a whole lot of future problems. However you have nothing to compare what you are doing, with. Except it self. So all looks good. I can not tell what this variation is, because you only express variance from what you think is normal.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I'm using `time` as an example (the first time I've run into this). It is different than other 'commands' because it executes a file. And this is the identification of the special case. The general case, as I hypothesize while asking for other examples in my edit above, is any command that executes a file. Which is why I suggested you specify that in the answer you provided. Actually, the general case may be more general as @doneal hinted at, but as I replied,much of those exceptions are by design for expediency so I think they unnecessarily complicate the broadest general case

Comment: @alchemy `time` doesn’t execute a file, it executes a command. Try running `time ls` and `cat ls` from your home directory to see why it makes sense for the behaviour to be different.

Comment: @StephenKitt does not `time` do exactly what the shell does. When you type `ls` both fork then both call one of the `exec?p?`s. I suspect the difference may be the OP calling `bash file-name`. Here bash is being different.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor yes, `bash file-name` executes a file, not a file, not a command. The point I’m trying to make is that alchemy’s generalisation doesn’t work, because most of the time what gets executed isn’t a named file (something that gets resolved using only the file system, by default in the current directory), but a named command (something that gets resolved with `PATH` etc.).

Comment: @StephenKitt I can't tell if we are in agreement (but suspect we are).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I think we are. My comment got messed up, I meant to write “`bash file-name` executes a file, not a command”.

Comment: @StephenKitt fair enough, the need for `./` is when running a command that executes *something*. `time` can execute either a file (a script, as in my case) or a command.

Comment: @Kusalananda I avoided details on `PATH` on purpose. The OP way not be ready, for this level of detail.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I see. You do what you think is right.