# Why can't I run mysql?

Tags: centos, mysql, xampp

I'm trying to import a database from Wamp to Xampp. I run Lampp first, then go to `/opt/lampp/bin` and run:

```
mysql (or mysqladmin ?) -u root -h localhost
```

but I get:

> mysql: command line not found

Why isn't it working?

Comment: Does [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/why-do-we-use-to-execute-a-file) answer your question? I'm not quite sure what the actual problem is

Comment: Also check this up [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525683/mysql-root-login-with-ssh-private-key) if you are fed up to input your password and username. Hopefully this saves some time to get started and early trial-and-error.

Comment: [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/387595/installed-mysql-but-cant-find-it)'s a similar question with some things to try and some questions to get you on the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically the current directory (`.`) is not inside the PATH for security reasons (assume a user puts an evil executable called `ls` in /tmp and then `root` executes it ...).

You can either call it explicitly:

```
./mysql -uroot -hlocalhost
```

Or you could add the folder to your PATH:

```
export PATH=/opt/lampp/bin:$PATH
mysql -uroot -hlocalhost
```

Comment: Thank you Johannes, That really helped me, in every tutorial I red, they didn t put the ./ that is used for the cd command. Once again, easy, but you can't guess it if you don't know it :) I'm really wonderinng why all the guides I red didn't talk about it... like [here](http://debaan.blogspot.com/2006/11/getting-started-mysql-on-centos.html) for instance

Comment: That tutorial uses the package mananger (yum) to install mysql, which puts the mysql in7bin(or rather /usr/bin) which is in $PATH. Other tutorials might be like "yeah well, I didn't think much, but the user will know" which obviously isn't always the case ..