# Shell Script not working whenever I run it

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have a simple script that terminates some processes and closes ports as below. I am running `metasploitable`.

[image: fuser script]

However, whenever I run this, it gives the below error. (note that on this file everyone has permissions)

[image: error]

Comment: Please paste the text instead of attaching the images.

Comment: See [Why do we use “./” to execute a file?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/why-do-we-use-to-execute-a-file)

Answer (score 1):

to run a script it must be executable `chmod +x portblock.sh` then to run it you must add ./ in the beginning

```
./portblock.sh
```

Comment: I am not getting the error : -bash: ./portblock.sh /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: Looks like you have a dos line ending file. The clue is the ^M. You need to re-save the file using Unix line endings.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you have executable permission for your script.

And then,

Run your script using `./portblock.sh` or using `sh portblock.sh`.

If you don't like to run the script with above mentioned way then update your `PATH` variable to the script directory.

Comment: I have 777 permissions on it...I am not getting the error : -bash: ./portblock.sh /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: file was edited by windows, you must run `dos2unix portblock.sh`

Comment: @Archemar thanks. But I need to install the program which seems not to be working in Exploitable

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372645/convert-dos2unix-line-endings-for-all-files-in-a-directory (hint: `sed -i s/\r//` )

Comment: Yes, as @Archemar said, You should run `dos2unix`. Line endings should use LF not CRLF.

Comment: its fine guys, the commands were very few so i created a new file using cat and it works fine thanks.