# What is the difference between executable that requires ```./``` with the one not requiring it?

Tags: make, executable

What is the difference between the following

`./executable`  and `executable`. Why is it, sometimes, some executable (non-Linux commands) don't require `./`?

If I have installed an executable through a makefile (a physics code) how can I remove it and install an updated version? Is removing `rm` the code sufficient? The executable, in this case, is executed without `./`

Comment: IMHO this is really 2 questions - for the first, see [Why do we use “./” (dot slash) to execute a file in Linux/UNIX?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/why-do-we-use-dot-slash-to-execute-a-file-in-linux-unix)

Comment: That is a different question! I understand the ./ but not sure of the one without it. The question there is concerning a linux command where as I am asking about an executable.

Comment: They are the same thing. All commands are executable, and all executables can be a command

Comment: What does "(non-Linux commands)" mean here?

Comment: @ilkkachu for example executable obtained from compiling a code or makefile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an UNIX environment (and even in other systems like DOS, Windows, etc) there are directories where the shell looks for executables. In an Unix environment it's defined in the `PATH` variable. You can see the directories in the `PATH` variable executing the following command:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

The result will be something like:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

As you can see, the variable is a list of directories separated by a colon. When you run a command, e.g. `ls`, the system will search for an executable in the first directory of the list (in the example, `/usr/local/sbin`). If it doesn't find a file named `ls` there, it will try the next directory, until it finds it. So if your `ls` command is located on `/usr/bin`, it will execute. Or, you'll get a command not found error if the shell cannot find it anywhere.

However, there are other ways to call an executable. Imagine you have two programs named `ls` in two directories in the `PATH`, and you want to run the second one. The way of doing that might be running `/usr/bin/ls`, so you specify which one you want.

The `.` is a shortcut for the current directory. So if you're at `/home/user`, `./configure` is a shortcut for `/home/user/configure`.

You can remove a file from the `PATH` by looking for the place it's located and removing it. However, you might prefer to manage binaries installed into your system through a package manager, available in most modern distributions (like rpm, dpkg, pacman, etc). If the Makefile creates several executables, it's going to be easier to remove them this way (also, the makefile might create some library files and several other things, that's why it's easier to use a package management tool). Sometimes a Makefile might bring an uninstall routine (i.e. make uninstall), but I'm not sure how often it happens. If you are updating a program through a new makefile, a new `make install` would likely replace the old binaries, but there's no guarantee of that.

You can always find out what is the executable for a certain command by running `which`. For instance, if you want to know where `ls` is:

```
$ which ls
/usr/bin/ls
```

Comment: Question /85429/ deprecates `which`. `command -V myCmd` is considered safer on Linux.

Comment: Thanks for your input, @Paul_Pedant, I'm really "outdated" as I haven't been using Linux for almost a decade and just returned last week. If you're familiar with the command would you please edit it? I'll take a closer look at it next weekend and don't feel confident enough to do it right now. By now I wasn't table to reproduce the same results yet in certain situations, i.e. my ls command, which is an alias (I assume there might be an option for that case, but I'll need sometime until I fully understand it).