# some linux commands needs explicit path, some not

Tags: bash, shell-script

I don't understand why some bash commands needs a explicit path and some not.

is there somewhere a complete list of commands that needs a explicit path?

#### example working:

```
chmod +x 2copyQ.tmp.sh ; 
./2copyQ.tmp.sh ;
```

that's working or it says `No such file or directory`

#### example not working:

```
chmod +x 2copyQ.tmp.sh ; 
2copyQ.tmp.sh ;
2copyQ.tmp.sh: command not found
```

Comment: Near-duplicate: [Why do we use "./" (dot slash) to execute a file in Linux/UNIX?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4430)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there somewhere a complete list of commands that needs a explicit path?

short answer : there is no such list.

long answer :

in most interactive shell, commands are search using `$PATH` variable. `PATH` is a list of colon separated directories to look for executable.

a sample  `PATH` looks like

```
 /home/archemar/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

(actual `PATH` are much longer)

when you issue command `foo`,

1. shell will search from left to right for an executable file named `foo` in directories listed in `PATH`, silently ignoring non exitent dir.
2. if an executable `foo` is found, the shell will run it.
3. if none is found, you'll get `foo: command not found` error.

If you use relative (`game1/foo`, `./foo`) or absolute filename (`/opt/tomcat/bin/start.sh` ), shell will look for that file and execute it (or complain if not found).

If you want shell to find executable in current directory, just add `.` (local dir) in `PATH`, for instance

```
.:/home/archemar/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Note that adding `.` in `PATH` is considered as a bad practice for security reasons.