# Ubuntu bash no such file but file is exist and type is executable

Tags: ubuntu

I am running the executable file at ubuntu 20 machine, and hitting error about `bash: No such file or directory`

```
$ /nexus-iq-cli -s http://localhost:8070/ -a admin:admin123 -i test .
bash: /nexus-iq-cli: No such file or directory
```

I have checked the file is 64bit and executable.
Is this file having problem or something else needed at my ubuntu machine?

```
  $ file nexus-iq-cli
    nexus-iq-cli: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, with debug_info, not stripped
```

Comment: Your command is `/nexus-iq-cli` but your `file` command uses `nexus-iq-cli` - were you in `/` then? Are you on a Raspberry Pi or other non-x86 system?

Comment: @muru yes that was the command given by tech person to run the executable file. i have tried with / or without / , both returned same bash error. i am in the correct directory at terminal already. not using raspberry, it is just my ubuntu machine.

Comment: Try `./nexus-iq-cli`. See [Why do we use "./" (dot slash) to execute a file in Linux/UNIX?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4432/65304)