# Linux Command to run a file

Tags: tar

I am trying to run a Foxitreader. I have run a tar on it. But why do I need to execute the setup with
Why do I have to run a file beginning with './' in Downloads? What does that mean?

./FoxitReader.enu.setup.1.1.0.0225(r205262).x64.run

Comment: What installation instructions are you following?

Comment: Are you asking [Why do we use "./" (dot slash) to execute a file in Linux/UNIX?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/why-do-we-use-dot-slash-to-execute-a-file-in-linux-unix)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we use "./" (dot slash) to execute a file in Linux/UNIX?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/why-do-we-use-dot-slash-to-execute-a-file-in-linux-unix)

Comment: Taking a wider view of your question "Why?". The `tar` delivers a package in a "crate". The `run` file contains the understanding of how to open the "crate", and unpack the contents onto the right "shelves" (which might be different on some machines or distros).

Answer (score 2):

Foxit distributes its Foxit PDF reader as a compressed archive (file ending .tar.gz: .tar indicates it is an archive, .gz indicates it is zipped).

Once you decompressed the file you have this .run file. This is a binary file that can be executed on the command line.
The prefix `./` tells your shell to look for the file in the current directory as the `.` is an identifier for "the current directory". You can check the directory you are in with the `pwd` command.

Answer (score 2):

In Linux and Unix like systems. the symbol `.`  means the current directory and the symbol `..` means the past directory

so `./X` ( X is binary file) tells your terminal should execute the X file binary

`.gz` is suffix for compressed file like `X.gz`
`.tar` is suffix for archives files like `X.tar`
we have other compressor commands in Linux like `bzip2` (with prefix `.bz2`)  but usually, we use gzip to compress files

For more information about tar see [here](https://man.archlinux.org/man/tar.1)

For more information about gzip see [here](https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/gzip/gzip.1.en)

Answer (score 0):

Compared to Windows, the `tar` file is just an archive, like `zip` is.

So what you've done is, you have unpacked the executable from the archive. **This is like extracting a `.zip` file to get an `.exe` file** on Windows.

But, like on Windows, here you *need to run* the executable to actually *run* the program.

You can run this executable (saved in the current folder) with `./FoxitReader.enu.setup.1.1.0.0225(r205262).x64.run`. Again, **this is equivalent to running an exe file**.

---

For the question: "why do I need `./` to run an executable?" — you don't always need it.

For example, when you type `ls` or `cp` or whatever, you run an executable. The thing is, the terminal needs to know *where* to find this program.

By default, when you don't type the path to the executable, the terminal searches for it in configured folders.

So, when you type `ls`, the terminal:

1. sees the command doesn't specify where `ls` is
2. looks in folders as defined with the `$PATH` variable (setting)
3. finds `ls` in `/bin/ls`
4. runs it

But, the `$PATH` setting doesn't usually have the current directory in it. That means you have to write the path to the executable, and the current folder has a special name `.`, in the same way as a parent folder is `..`.

Without specifing that the FoxitReader "exe" is in the current (or a different directory) [with `./` or `Downloads/` etc.], it wouldn't find it and wouldn't run it.