# I was trying to run clang file

Tags: kali-linux, executable

I am new to Kali Linux i was trying to run clang file which i did but a `a.out` file appears what to do next?

```
zsh: no such file in directory: /a.out
```

I have trying to do it so many time please help

Comment: See also [Why do we use "./" (dot slash) to execute a file in Linux/UNIX?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/why-do-we-use-dot-slash-to-execute-a-file-in-linux-unix)

Comment: It may be that you have simply forgotten to type the initial `.` in `./a.out` to execute the `a.out` executable in the current directory (`./`).